# Добавить json объект в общий массив

Tags: python, json

```
a_dict = {}
for row in re:
   x = {"id": str(row[0]) ,"name": str(row[1]) , "key": str(row[2]) , "realName": str(row[3]) }
```

В цикле перебираю выдачу из БД и пытаюсь сформировать json строку в таком виде

```
{"data": {"id": 1, "name": "NAME", "key": "KEY", "realName": "RNAME"},{"id": 2, "name": "NAME", "key": "KEY", "realName": "RNAME"} }
```

Мне приходит на ум сделать это при помощи объединения строк т.е. в цикле объединять строки а потом просто преобразовать в json объект. Может есть более правильное решение?

Comment: Если у вас много данных с одинаковой структурой, то надо обращаться к модулям, которые работают с табулированной структурой данных. Например, pandas.

Comment: `payloads = (dict(zip(('id', 'name', 'key', 'realName'), row)) for row in re); result = {'data': list(payloads)}`.